# How to call a js function when an element ID is clicked.

Tags: javascript

I have a web telemetry system that sends metadata to a server on element clicks.  I'm looking to write JS that would allow for me to fire a function on click of specific elements by their ID.

I also would like to know if there is a js function i could write that would include html attributes from my telemetry system on the element when it is clicked, defined by the ID.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Change `YourId` with your element ID name without any symbols

```
document.getElementById("YourID").onclick = function(){

//do something after this line

}
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pu3antasyah/of0q058v/4/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
//calling function by name
document.getElementById("Button").onclick = sendToServer;
//or
    document.getElementById("Button").addEventListener("click", sendToServer, false);

    function sendToServer() {

      //some code
      console.log("the button clicked");

    }
```

```html
<button id='Button'>send to server</button>
```

```js
document.getElementById("Button").onclick = function() {
  //code
  console.log("the button clicked");
};

//or 
document.getElementById("Button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //code
  console.log("the button clicked");
}, false);
```

```html
<button id='Button'>send to server</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
  var e= document.getElementById('container');
  
  if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display=='')
    {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else 
    {
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }

});
```

```html
<button id="button">Button</button>
<div id="container">
  <p> This is a paragraph </p>
</div>
```

Read more about [document.getElementById() at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)